# Get the name of the variable which has the highest/biggest value with PHP

Tags: php

I have 4 variables and each of those have an integer assigned to them. Could anybody please let me know how I can get the name of the variable which has the highest value?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you assigning those values?

Comment: Why do you want the *name* of the variable? You're probably doing something very wrong if you need to engage in this kind of meta-programming.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a solution to the question you asked:

```
$arr = compact('v1', 'v2', 'v3', 'v4');
arsort($arr);
$name = key($arr);
// get the value: ${$name}
```

However, having the variables stored in an array in the first place would make more sense.  A better setup would be:

```
$arr = array('v1' => 543, 'v2' => 41, 'v3' => 1, 'v4' => 931);
arsort($arr);
$name = key($arr);
// get the value: $arr[$name]
```

Answer (score 2):

Given four variables:

```
$a = 1;
$b = 3;
$c = 4;
$d = 2;
```

You can use [`compact`](http://us.php.net/compact) to turn them into an associative array:

```
$array = compact('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
var_dump($array); // array('a' => 1, 'b', => 3, 'c' => 4, 'd' => 2);
```

And then find the maximum key/value:

```
$max_key = $max_value = null;

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
  if (is_null($max_value) || $value > $max_value) {
    $max_key = $key; $max_value = $value;
  }
}
```